# Adding a control to update a widget

Tags: java, android-widget

I have added an `ImageButton` in my widget layout to trigger the widget update. My layout is :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#7F7F7F"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/marge_widget" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/Text1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="8"
       android:textColor="#FF0000"
       android:textSize="20sp" />

 <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/UpdateButton"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In my `onUpdate` function, I attach a `PendingIntent`to my button like this :

```
    intent = new Intent(contexte,myApp.class);        
    intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);        
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,appWidgetId,intent,0);       
    vue.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.UpdateButton,pendingIntent);
```

The problem is that nothing happens when I click on the widget's button...

What's wrong with my code?

I can add that my widget is correctly updated when created or resized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your widget's ID in the Intent extra. Note that the doc for ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE specifies an extra which is a list of IDs.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE

Looking at the Android source for AppWidgetProvider.onReceive, if there are no widget IDs, then it doesn't call onUpdate. Thus you need to add your widget ID as an intent extra.

Unfortunately, the next problem is that Android reuses PendingIntent instances when the underlying intent is only different in the extras. That means that when the user creates a new widget instance (with a new ID), the PendingIntent it fetches will still have the old widget ID in it. You can get around that problem by using the PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag in your getBroadcast call.

```
intent = new Intent(contexte, myApp.class);        
intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[] { appWidgetId });
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);       
vue.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.UpdateButton, pendingIntent);
```

Now this will work for the LATEST widget instance that has updated. However, you still have a problem if the user adds more than one instance of your widget. Only the latest one's button will work. I've solved this issue in the past by storing all the widget IDs in SharedPreferences. Then, rather than just adding {appWidgetId}, you can retrieve the list of IDs and add them all. I won't try to implement that here, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Adding the line `intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,new int[] {appWidgetId});`didn't help. My problem was elsewhere : the `intent`was created with the `myApp` class instead of the `myAppWidgetProvider`class. Now this is corrected, the widget is correctly updated after each click on the "updateButton".